# Reordering a Items in Rows in a Subset of Columns in Pandas DataFrame Given Information in Another Subset of Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

e = [{'E1': 'A', 'E2': 'B', 'E3': 'C', 'EDAY1': 0, 'EDAY2': 1, 'EDAY3': 2}, {'E1': 'B', 'E2': '0', 'E3': '0', 'EDAY1': 2, 'EDAY2': -1, 'EDAY3': -1}, {'E1': 'F', 'E2': 'A', 'E3': 'D', 'EDAY1': 5, 'EDAY2': 5, 'EDAY3': 2}]
df = pd.DataFrame(e)
display(df)
```

Output:

```
    E1  E2  E3  EDAY1   EDAY2   EDAY3
0   A   B   C   0       1       2
1   B   0   0   2      -1      -1
2   F   A   D   5       5       2
```

Where `E1` through `E3` are events, and `EDAY1` through `EDAY3` are the days that the corresponding events occurred on. Note that:

- If no event occurred, it is labelled as '0' and the corresponding `EDAY` is set to `-1`
- Event `E1` has greater precedence than `E2` and `E2` than `E3`
- Event precedence does not correspond to `EDAY` (see the last row)
- Some events occurred on the same day

I would like to turn these events into 10 char long strings based on the following criteria:

1. Each character position on the string roughly corresponds to the day that the event occurred
2. Days where there were no events will be represented by the character '0'
3. Events that occurred on the same day will be sorted by level of precedence and set immediately adjacent to one another (I understand that this is not a perfect representation, but it will do for now)

Therefore given the example above, I would like to have the following representation:

```
    E1  E2  E3  EDAY1   EDAY2   EDAY3   E_STR
0   A   B   C   0       1       2       ABC0000000
1   B   0   0   2      -1      -1       00B0000000
2   F   A   D   5       5       2       00D00FA000
```

Please note that this is not homework but I am a Python and Pandas newbie, and this has me stumped.

Comment: can you explain how you got this`00D00AF000`?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake - fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just share my way for this question , I using `wide_to_long` to flatten you original dataframe , then exclude the -1 , and `zip` all the value into `list` of `list` , bad structure , but no worry we just need it create the pair of values and position (In my understanding the EDAY is the position of the char in E )

```
newdf=pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['E','EDAY'],i='index',j='drop').loc[lambda x : x.EDAY!=-1]
newdf.EDAY+=newdf.groupby(['index','EDAY']).cumcount()# here is to protect when two position show up same time
newdf=newdf.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

---

After beyond reshape we using for loop to create the char you need

```
l=[]
for x ,y in zip(newdf.E,newdf.EDAY):
    xvar=list('0000000000')
    for idx,z in enumerate(y):
        xvar[z]=x[idx]
    l.append(''.join(xvar))
l
Out[111]: ['ABC0000000', '00B0000000', '00D00FA000']
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong, but when I try `newdf.EDAY+=newdf.groupby(['index','EDAY']).cumcount()# here is to protect when two position show up same time`, it tells me: `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')`

Comment: Fixed it - was an issue because `newdf.EDAY` was type object, which I turned to numeric.

Comment: @oort aha :-) -